# How to change video codec that is being use for videos?

Tags: video, codecs

I need to change video codec, because of [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1471156#post9227044)

I'm new to ubuntu. How to do it?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are looking for here. It's clear that you think you need to change a media files codec, but that's highly unlikely it's far more likely that you need to install a codec to support a video file that you have. To change the video codec of a movie you need to re-encode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download SMplayer - look it up how to install software in ubuntu if you haven't done that before. In SMplayer in settings you can choose which codec to use if SMplayer won't resolve your problem on it's own.